# Ajax response is not changing my viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I bind a value and a list and want to change it from inside an Ajax callback. I retrieve a fresh value in `.get()`, but when I the callback for `.get()` actually happens, and I assign the retrieved value to my view model's property, the UI does not refresh. Here is my code:

```
function SearchViewModel() {
    this.count = ko.observable(count);
    this.list = ko.observableArray(list);
    //I had count and list before I assigned.
    this.addPage = function() {
       var form = $('#form');
       var serializedData = form.serialize();
       $.get("{% url 'search:search' %}", serializedData, function(response){
           console.log(this.count); // it's undefined here.
           this.count = response.count;
           console.log(this.count); // it's the value I want to updated, e.g. 20. But UI is not refreshedenter code here
       });
   };
}
```

I want to update a list too in the callback, but right now even a simple `count` value is not being updated. I read about many related solutions on stackoverflow, and tried several, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
this.count(response.count);
```

That should do the trick.

For more information about observables check out http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

You also have a potential scope issue in your code. When you are reffering to this in the callback you are not guaranteed that you get the scope of the viewModel. Therefore you should add this line outside of the callback:

```
var self = this;
```

And inside the callback you should change to:

```
self.count(response.count);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this before. It doesn't work. Let me check the error. It seems in .get(), I cannot pass in anything related to this.count, and after I get result I cannot send out.

Comment: Even when you change to self.count?

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot! I never thought it's this reason. I tried many advanced solutions they didn't work....

Comment: Scope in JavaScript is a bit different than what you are used to if you have a Java or c# background. Please mark it as answer if it solved you issue.

Comment: javascript closure can be a bit of a pain to deal with. If you are going to have a javascript object with deep scopes, its generally a good idea to store the 'this' context in a variable, so you can access that context in a deeper scope within that object.